# One-to-many merge with same column names in proc sql

Tags: sql, sas

I am looking to join these 2 tables by ordered by ptid and tx_code.
what is the ideal way to join so that each observation in dat2 is returned with repeated info from dat1?

```
data baseline;
input ptid  age gender $ stat stat_date creat tx_code datnum$;
cards;
123 40 M A 02/15/2004 1.2 3 1
456 29 F A 06/05/2009 1.5 2 1
789 53 M D 01/10/2007 2.0 1 1
;
run;

data followup;
 input ptid tx_code stat stat_date wgt hgt  organ datnum $;
cards;
123 3 A 02/15/2004 60 150 ki 2
123 3 A 10/05/2004 75 150 ki 2
456 2 A 06/05/2009 95 173 SKP 2
456 2 A 12/30/2009 95 173 SKP 2
456 2 A 05/05/2010 93 173 SKP 2
456 2 A 10/20/2010 85 173 SKP 2
456 2 D 11/10/2010 . 173 SKP 2
789 1 A 01/10/2007 65 180 pta 2
789 1 A 06/25/2007 60 180 pta 2 
789 1 L 06/25/2008 . . pta 2
;
run;
```

Comment: You will have to rename one of those STAT_DATE variables you want to keep both.  Also why is one a date and the other a string?

Comment: that was just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join using proc sql. If you only want distinct observations, use "select distinct" instead of "select"

```
proc sql;
    create table resultant_table as select
        a.*, b.wgt, b.hgt, b.organ, b.stat as stat2, b.stat_date as stat_date2
        from baseline as a
        left join followup as b
        on a.ptid = b.ptid and a.tx_code = input(b.tx_code, 8.);
quit;
```

Comment: Please don't name your result table `join`. it is confusing.

Comment: @superfluous, how can each stat_date and stat from t2 be returned, given they the dates are different at each obs? I tried a coalesce, but it only captures the 1st date.

Comment: You just need to include them in the list of variables you want to include in the resultant table - check out the edit I just made and let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: I get the variable  already exist  warning message on the vars they share in common.

Comment: The warning doesn't prevent the join from working properly. If you want to prevent SAS from displaying a warning, you can state "a.var1, a.var2, a.var3..., b.var1, b.var2...." to get exactly the variables you want in your output.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as such. If not, let us know what's still going wrong!

Comment: @superfluous how could I estimate the freq of some variable base on unique id's? I have been doing a proc freq, but I am afraid the output is returning on the number of obs. any idea how i could do this?

Comment: What do you want to find the frequency of? It sounds like you may be best off posting a new question with some sample data.